# How do I set the classpath on Mac and is it necessary?

Tags: java, macos, classpath

I'm a complete beginner to Java, and initially downloaded and installed Android Studio, latest JDK and SDK libraries and tried to follow the "Build My First App" tutorial through developer.andoird.com before realizing I need to stick to basics and learn Java first.

Now I'm trying to follow a Java Beginner's tutorial which said it explains the process for setting up Java on PC, Mac and other platforms but is only explaining it for PC. I'm stuck on how to set a classpath as the tutorial explains it for PC only.

I'm so sorry if these are basic questions, I couldn't really find anything in past forums that explained it in beginner terms that I could understand. What is a classpath and why is it necessary to set it up? How do I set it for Mac? I read a number of forums saying you don't really need to set one or that it's not necessary, while others imply otherwise.

*edit: to clarify, I'm taking the Udemy Java Programming for Beginners, stuck on the setting classpath and checking classpath part of the tutorial prior to learning how to execute the basic Hello World.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class path is a setting passed to the Java runtime. It's basically a list of folders for the Java runtime to look for class files. The simplest class path is the current folder:

```
java -classpath . MyClass
```

Java will execute `MyClass.class` if it's in the current folder. You will need more complex class path setups when your project gets more complex (when you start to use libraries). For starters you can stick with the current folder.

Answer (score 0):

CLASSPATH is what you use to tell the JVM how to find the .class files it needs at compile and runtime.  Yes, you need it for all operating systems.

The best way to do this is using the -classpath option on javac.exe and java.ext.

When you start creating and deploying Java EE projects on an app server, you'll learn that they have conventions for CLASSPATH that you'll need to know and follow when you package your application (e.g. WAR files assume WEB-INF/classes is head of CLASSPATH; all JARs in WEB-INF/lib are added to CLASSPATH for you).

You don't need an environment variable CLASSPATH to be set.  I would discourage you from having one, since it changes with each and every project you run.